# Call a singleton method in OGNL Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, singleton, ognl

I need to access a method of a singleton class to obtain a parameter

The prototype of the call from Java code is:

```
SosConstant.getInstance().getParameter("type");
```

I have a set of parameters that modify the view, so I need to access these data directly from the JSP

How can I write a

```
<s:parameter value="...
```

and a

```
<s:if test="..
```

that use these data?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html - find 'static method' on the page

Comment: Thank for your help
I've tried as noticed in the page (@class@method(args)) with no results.

So I've tried with a simpler example

         <s:property value="@java.lang.Long@MAX_VALUE" />
print 9223372036854775807 in the right way

         <s:property value="@java.lang.Long@valueOf('32')" />
doesn't print 32 as expected

What is wrong?

Comment: try `<s:property value="@java.lang.Long@valueOf(32)" />`, with no quotes surrounding the `32`

Comment: I've obtained no changes. My project is using http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ognl/ognl/3.0.6

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

,after a lot of seach, to my struts.xml.
I think that these constants are not well documented. Where could I find them in the apache struts website?

Comment: There are two OGNL pages linked to in the tag docs, one from the OGNL basics page: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html

Comment: OGNL is pretty intuitive until you need to do something like this, the link provided is missing a critical example (the example field is blank) with regard to this particular issue. I don't recall if struts explicitly links to the OGNL language guide but for any struts2 developer it should be read at least once in full: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html

Comment: @Quaternion Yes, we're still having some wiki export issues.

Comment: @DaveNewton confluence is interesting, a wiki by developers for developers... as ironic as this may sound I'm not convinced it's merits are significantly ahead of a wiki developed by developers for the technically ignorant. I actually prefer to work in the later. The seemingly simple task of updating the tag reference to state if a tag attribute is or is not parsed by default as an ognl expression either requires that I make a lot of issue requests (because that information is actually extracted from annotations) or that I write an integration test battery(selenium)... I'm doing the later.

Comment: @Quaternion Personally I've not been a fan of pulling so much from the code, especially the examples, and have lobbied to stop at least that practice. I love Confluence, but for a few reasons it's a pain for the S2 docs.

Comment: @SimoneBuzzi be aware that this was disabled on purpose as static access can be potentially dangerous and I'm planing to remove it completely in the next major release. Maybe it won't be needed if I implement my security mechanism to avoid access to particular classes - should be available in 2.3.18 ;-)

Comment: I have updated the page, please report any such problem - I can simple re-edit the page and re-export it in few seconds ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting action property and provide getter method.

```
private Object type; 

public Object getType(){
  return type;
}
```

in the action or other initialization method

```
type = SosConstant.getInstance().getParameter("type");
```

then in JSP you can access it as usual

```
<s:property value="type"/>
```

or

```
<s:if test="type == 'some type'">
...
</s:if>
```

OGNL has a syntax that allows to call a static method, but it's prohibited for the security reasons, so by default this setting is turned off. To get the instance of any object you need either create that object (that is not possible in your case) or use another object that returns the instance. The action object instance is most suitable for this purpose. All you need is create a method that returns an instance of the object (singleton in your case).

```
public SosConstant getSosConstant(){
  return SosConstant.getInstance();
}
```

then you can use it in JSP like

```
<s:property value="sosConstant.getParameter('type')"/>
```

or

```
<s:if test="sosConstant.getParameter('type') == 'some type'">
...
</s:if>
```

Just one step around this but it's the same thing in OGNL.

Comment: Thank Roman. I think this is a good solution; but I have two constraints
1) the project is auto generated and use a standardized BaseAction shared in N project that can't contain an access to general purpose data
2) this option is used by the primary menu of the webapp, so I need to share this method in all the actions, it's a bad solution in a long term project
I'm trying to use singleton for these reasons

Comment: 1) Action beans are for general access on the view layer and if you don't want to give access to it, then you should copy a value to the property that has an access. 2) I don't understand: do you want to set or get HTTP or internal parameter? Singleton is a bad solution, however you may try create an interceptor.

Comment: My project use a set of library that wrap struts2 actions to create a group of BaseAction that contains 80% of the code I need in my projects.
Here I need to access ad hoc global properties that aren't managed from libs.
These properties modify the behaviour of a first level menu, so I need them everywhere.
I think that the singleton is one of the possible solutions for this problem because they rarelly change (I can destroy singleton by code), but an interceptor could be a solution too.
Which advantages can I have?

Comment: This is a project specific if you intercept an action that requires one more properties it can't get during execution time, so prepare those properties or inject then directly to the action instance. The example used by the framework is `ParameterAware` interface that your action can implement.